# How do I fix my anaconda python distribution?

Tags: python, anaconda

All seemed to be working fine in my anaconda distribution on Mac. Then I tried to install the postgres library psycopg2 with conda install psycopg2. That threw an error. Something about permissions. But now nothing works. Now it can't even find the conda executable or start ipython. 
-bash: conda: command not found
Should condo executable be in ~/ananconda/bin.
The directory is there but no conda executable.

Anyone know what might have happened or how I can recover from this?

Comment: Do you have anything in `~/anaconda/envs/`?

Comment: No. Not even hidden files/dirs.

Comment: I installed `psycopg2` with `conda` on my Mac yesterday (I installed PostgreSQL first) but didn't run into any permissions issues. I'm afraid I can only recommend reinstalling anaconda, but good luck with the other answers!

Comment: Did you use `sudo` at any point when running `conda` or the Anaconda installer?

Comment: I might have tried sudo after the first one failed.

Comment: You should avoid using sudo with Anaconda. It's unnecessary, and using it will cause conda to write files with permissions that won't let them be modified unless sudo is used again (hence the permissions errors).

Answer (score 5):

You're going to have to reinstall Anaconda to fix this. Without conda, there's not much you can do to clean up the broken install.

Comment: I reinstalled anaconda. It wasn't too hard. All seems fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem. Download latest miniconda and use correct paths for preinstalled anaconda folder

```
bash ~/Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -bfp ~/anaconda2
```

I couldn't find the original thread where I found this.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem - was able to use conda from an anaconda prompt (found in the anaconda folder) and install packages I needed